# Can ellipsis be iterated in R like *args in Python?

Tags: r

The newly-defined function to sum inputs:

```
mysum=function(...){
return(sum(...))
invisible(...)
}

> mysum(1,2,3,4)
[1] 10
```

What if I don't use the `sum` function?I mean this:

```
mysum=function(...){
s=0
for(i in ...){
s=s+i
}
return(s)
}
```

It doesn't work. Can `...` be iterated?

In Python,it's simple:

```
def mysum(*args):
    s=0
    for i in args:
        s+=i
    return(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `c()` on ellipsis before the loop, and assign it inside the function:

```
mysum=function(...){
  vec = c(...)
  s=0
  for(i in vec){
    s=s+i
  }
  return(s)
}

mysum(1,2,3)
[1] 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

The usual route is to stuff it into a list and then iterate over the list:

```
my_fun <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  # do stuff with ellipses args.
}
```

Whether you use `lapply`, go straight for named arguments or just loop over (`for (i in seq_along(args)) {args[[i]]}`) is up to you.

If you assume `...` only contains vectors, you could do:

```
args <- unlist(list(...))
sum(args)
```